# What programs in Windows 10 produce sounds?

Tags: windows, audio

In Windows 8 or 7 you could you see exactly what program makes sound, but how can I see that in Windows 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Volume mixer is exactly the same as its always been.

[image] Just rightclick on the volume control icon, and pick the mixer.

Comment: That's it, thanks. I never clicked right button on icon.